# Print Web content via Zebra RW420 printer

Tags: html, cordova, zebra-printers, printing-web-page

currently I am doing a phonegap based software, and now I want to print the web content via the Zebra RW420 printer. I looked at the Zebra sdk for android then I found that it only can print pain text and bitmap image. Is that a way to print the HTML format file via the Zebra RW420 printer? Thanks

Comment: can you convert the web view content to an image? You can do that easily in iOS and then just print the image out using the zebra sdk.

Comment: Thanks, I made it in Android as well. Converse the text to png file then print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to print the Web content on Zebra RW420 is turn the web content into an PNG/BMP image. In android, you can use webview.capturepicture to get the current web content into an PNG file. Then this PNG file can be print out via Zebra SDK.